# responseXML.xml empty string after POSTing to WCF Service

Tags: xml, wcf, vbscript, asp-classic

I am calling a WCF Service in the following way:

```
Dim SOAPResponse, SOAPRequest, serviceUrl, strResult
serviceUrl = "https://api.mydomain/Services/myAPIService.svc" 
Set SOAPRequest =  Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
SOAPRequest = "this is where my xml gets built"
Dim oXmlHTTP : Set oXmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
oXmlHTTP.setOption 2, 13056
oXmlHTTP.Open "POST", serviceUrl, False 
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=""http://tempuri.org/ImyAPIService/InsertPerson"""
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(SOAPRequest)
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IMyApiService/InsertPerson"
oXmlHTTP.send SOAPRequest
```

The SOAPRequest builds up a valid soap envelope, and then posts it to the server. The issue is that when I post to the service, my XmlHTTP.responseText is valid and contains the soap reply, but the XmlHTTP.responseXML.xml is an empty string.

The responseText returned as an example is below:

```
--uuid:17c8815c-33cd-4ccd-aaab-f0246cc26f65+id=2
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">
      http://tempuri.org/IMyApiService/InsertPersonResponse
    </a:Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <InsertPersonResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <InsertPersonResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApi.Models.Response" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ErrorDetails i:nil="true" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApi.Models.Response.Base"/>
        <IsSuccessful xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApi.Models.Response.Base">false</IsSuccessful>
        <b:ID>0</b:ID>
      </InsertPersonResult>
    </InsertPersonResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
--uuid:17c8815c-33cd-4ccd-aaab-f0246cc26f65+id=2--
```

I am guessing that this is because the xml isn't valid as my content type is application/soap+xml, so the --uuid bit and the other soap related info is not valid xml.

If I change the content type to text/xml, the service rejects the request as the content type is incorrect.

Basically I need to grab the IsSuccessful and the ID values from the response to then proceed with my function, any thoughts on how I can amend either the service or my vbscript so I can use the responseXML.xml and interrogate that as needed?

I would rather be able to interrogate the xml rather than a messy routine searching through the responseText string.

Comment: From http://www.jose.it-berater.org/msxml/responsexml_property_ixmlhttprequest.htm  Quote: The supported MIME types for MSXML 6.0 are: "text/xml", "application/xml" or anything that ends with "+xml", for example "application/rss+xml".
 
The supported MIME types for versions prior to MSXML 6.0 are: "text/xml", "application/xml".  End Quote:    As you are using 6.0 the MIME content type should be fine

Comment: I am using 6 as you can see in the first chunk of code. The call is successfully made but having no luck in handling the response properly.

From what I can tell, the main reason that the responseXML.xml property isn't set is that the XML is invalid, and the only part of it would be the SOAP contents at the top and bottom